# Как называется библиотека которая эмулирует клики и передвежение мыши в node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите, пожалуйста как называется библиотека, которая может эмулировать клики мыши, клики по клавиатуре (что-то похожее есть в python, py-auto-gui)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs

> Node.js Desktop Automation. Control the mouse, keyboard, and read the screen.
>
> RobotJS supports Mac, Windows, and Linux.